# power query editor won't refresh until I register my IP address

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I used to import data from an organization's Azure SQL Database, which I had to register my IP address in order to load data.
I no longer use this source and deleted the permission and I can't refresh/load data anymore without registering first (even on other pbix files).

Any ideas?